# Extracting population by using web scraping in Python from dynamic graph

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My task is to iterate all over US zipcodes in https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/23022/#stats and extract from the graph below the number for each year.

This link is an example for one zipcode area. after I extract them all I need to put them in a Pandas dataframe (which is quite easy), tried to look in other posts but can't seem to solve this.

Looked into the elements in the html but it is very unclear.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/23022/#stats'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

match = soup.findAll('tr')
print(match)

years = ['Historical ' + str(year) for year in range(2005, 2019)]

columns = ['ZIP Code', *years]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

[image: Sample graph]

Comment: There are an awful lots of zip codes. Is there a specific list of zipcodes you are interested in?

Comment: I need every zip code listed in that site (United States) from the year range 2005-2018 @QHarr

Comment: Aren't the zip codes pulled from a database you have to pay for access to? I looked at a free list from https://simplemaps.com/data/us-zips and the number is huge but I saw a lot of those don't have data when tried against your required data source. I am trying to think of a fair way to get data without swamping server with thousands of requests.

Comment: I got the assignment from a company im about to work for. So in legal manner its checked and verified.

Comment: Can't you get a paid for data dump?  https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to swamp the server. It looks like it queries a background database for data based on a zipcode and not all zipcodes have associated data. If you can determine a suitable range then use that in an iterable such as a list. A simply try except against all zip codes would be a very large number of requests and you would need to start thinking about batching requests, spreading over time, adding in pauses and switching to asynchronous requests.

The chart data can be extracted from a JavaScript object within the response text and parsed with `json` library. I assume that the years are consistent across responses.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re, json

results = []
columns = ['zip']

with requests.Session() as s:
    
    s.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    
    for code in range(23022, 23025): 
        
        url = f'https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/{code}/#stats'
        r = s.get(url)
        
        try:
            res = re.search(r'var data = (\[.*\])', r.text).group(1)
            data = json.loads(res)[0]['values']
            values = [i['y'] for i in data]
            values.insert(0, code)
            results.append(values)
            
            if values and len(columns) == 1:
                columns.extend([i['x'] for i in data])
        except:
            pass

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = columns)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, my task is just to pull it from the graph that's why I tried to use beautiful soup otherwise would used uszipcode python library

Comment: That is where the graph values come from. A script tag. I just used regex to more readily grab the appropriate items. Print `data` in the loop and you will see the x, y chart values. If you view the page source, or disable JS in browser, you will see an empty chart as JS needs to run to populate the chart.